# How to reduce a covariance matrix after clustering?

Tags: covariance, asset-allocation, cluster

I have an `N = 100` covariance matrix. I am clustering the covariance matrix say into `5 clusters`.

How can I compute the reduced covariance matrix of weighted cluster means which has `dimension = 5x5`?

In particular, I am working on an algorithm for financial asset allocation. This algorithm first performs an allocation on clustered returns. Initially, I have 100 stocks to allocate, but after this step, I am left with only 5 clusters. In the second and last step of the allocation, I would like to run a quadratic optimization that minimizes the portfolio variance. Nevertheless, for doing so, I would need to reduce the covariance matrix to a dimension equal to the number of clusters.

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi: if you have a cluster of stocks, then that cluster has a "time series of returns" embedded in it so you should be able to compute the covariance of those returns with the time series of returns of any other cluster. The variances are just the variances of the 5 return series implied by the 5 clusters.

Comment: Note that you should use the same weighting scheme for the covariance and variances that you used to get the means. Not sure what you're weighting by ? or why ?

Comment: agree with @markleeds if your clusters are defined by some allocations then you can directly compare timeseries of those clusters to get their covariances

Comment: FWIW in one paper I read a while ago, inside each cluster they were using equal weighting (EW). However that may not be how other authors do it.

Comment: By cluster having a time series of returns, do you mean that each period I calculate say 5 clusters using a weighting scheme (say equally weighted) and then, once I have calculated the time series of cluster returns, I can calculate the VarCov matrix 5x5? Or else how do I get to use the same weighting scheme for the VarCov that I used for the means? Because in this way I would have a look-ahead-bias, unless I reserve the first say 100 periods to estimate the VarCov and then I update it each step and run the optimization...

Comment: Hi: I didn't know you were dealing with look ahead bias. In that case, you'd have to assume that you only have a certain amount of data and not use the rest of it until its available. As far as the time series themselves, for a cluster, you take the returns of the companies in the cluster and add them so that you have a "cluster" return at any point in time t. So, that way you can construct a time series of cluster returns.  I'm not sure about the weighting because I didn't understand what weighting you were using for the means or why ?